# $.mobile.changePage is not loading next dynamic page properly

Tags: jquery, json, windows-phone-7, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am developing windows mobile 7 application using jQuery mobile and PhoneGap(1.9.0). I have multiple html pages in application  and data in all pages is loaded via JSON parsing and need storage of some data.  So I use localStorage for data storage(because windows browser not support database yet through phonegap). And in windows browser local storage is only working with phonegap's deviceready event.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", mymethod, false);

function mymethod(){

}
```

every thing is working fine except that when I navigating between the pages white screen come first and then new page will come . which look bad .

I use `window.location.href='page2.html';`  (every method works fine but delay in navigating between pages)

to navigate between screen .

But when I use

```
$.mobile.changePage("page2.html");
```

then white screen will disappear but my deviceready method will not work and blank screen with some static data(header and footer ) will come. Please tell me where I am wrong. How should I use `$.mobile.changePage("page2.html");` and in next page my page is loaded with content from local Storage or from json parsing.  or use  `window.location.href='page2.html';` but without white flashy screen .

I hope you all understand my question.
Is there any solution for this problem.

Comment: @jer - there is quite a lot more that could have been edited...  If you are already editing a post make sure that you deal with all the problems...

Answer (score 1):

You should use `$.mobile.changePage("page2.html");` so jqm will load this page with Ajax (and can do a nice transition). There will not be a deviceready event again (as you stay in the page), but you could catch a `pageshow` event when the page is shown.

(From the docs: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/api/events.html)

```
$( 'div' ).live( 'pageshow',function(event, ui){
  alert( 'This page was just hidden: '+ ui.prevPage);
});
```

Comment: But what about my JSON request and localStorage . In windows phone localStorage will work only in deviceready event.

Comment: I tried it but my dynamic data is not loaded . Only static headers and footers are shown.

Comment: So, if you can get a valid reference to localStorage in the deviceReady event, can't you assign it to a (global) variable you can access later? I can't believe you can only use it white the deviceready event is active...

Comment: When I use $.mobile.changePage("page2.html");then page loading method is not called. even in .live()  method the alert is also not invoked .

Comment: I think pageshow method is not called by windows phone browser. Can there be any solution.

Comment: So, have you tested this in Google Chrome? That's the first browser (on the desktop) where I test my jqm apps... You'll get nice feedback on your javascript errors etc. I you have it working there, port it to Windows Mobile....

Comment: Even I firstly test my jqm app on chrome. Every thing on chrome is working fine.But in windows mobile that is not working according to our requirement.